# SQL where x or y but not both

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that lists restaurants that serve either chicken of beef, something close to this:

```
Res   Meat
res1  chicken
res1  chicken
res1  beef
res2  chicken
res2  chicken
res3  beef
```

and I'm trying to write a query that returns which restaurants only provide chicken OR beef but not both without eliminating duplicates from the result.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: sorry... im using db2

Comment: You could use a query to check the count of distinct kinds of meat for each restaurant. If it's 1, the restaurant only serves one sort of meat (chicken/beef). Then take the result and extract the duplicates.

Comment: thank you for the insight, it helped me visualize how to get to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
create table tab
(
   Res   varchar(10), 
   Meat varchar(10)
)

insert into tab ( Res, Meat ) values ( 'res1', 'chicken' )
insert into tab ( Res, Meat ) values ( 'res1', 'chicken' )
insert into tab ( Res, Meat ) values ( 'res1', 'beef' )    
insert into tab ( Res, Meat ) values ( 'res2', 'chicken' )
insert into tab ( Res, Meat ) values ( 'res2', 'chicken' )    
insert into tab ( Res, Meat ) values ( 'res3', 'beef' )

select Res
from (
select distinct Res,Meat
from tab ) T
group by Res
having count(1) = 1
```

Comment: I tried this and the result shows each restaurant and which meat they sell once (ie res1 chick, res1 beef, res2 chick, res3 beef) :( I need it to show only the name of the restaurant that sells either one but not both

Comment: that does it! I just need it to show duplicates but I'm sure I can figure that out, thanks

Comment: @user2173523 I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget, you can also vote for the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE rest 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     Res varchar(20),
     Meat varchar(20) 
    );

INSERT INTO rest
(Res,Meat)
VALUES
('res1','chicken'),
('res1', 'chicken'),
('res1', 'beef'),
("res2", 'chicken'),
("res2", 'chicken'),
( 'res3', 'beef' )

select Res from 
  (select distinct Res,Meat from rest ) test
group by Res
having count(1) = 1
```

[Example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82518/3/0),

Comment: Please don't post answers with just links in. If the link breaks then the answer is useless!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the except operator

```
select * from table
where meat = 'chicken' or meat = 'Beer'

except

select * from table
where meat = 'chicken' and meat = 'Beer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select Res 
from rest
group by Res
having count(distinct Meat) = 1
```